# Verify if parameter passed to function is array not

Tags: php, function, oop

Let suppose i have function

```
public function test($dataid){
    .........   
}
```

now i want to run function only when `$dataid` must be an array. if not than it will be not work

ifi passed a string for example `test("string")` it wouldn't run.

i know `is_array()` but is there any other solluton ?

And if value is empty it will be automatically convert to array

Comment: Other than `is_array`, you could use type checking..

Comment: public function test((array)$dataid){

Comment: how can i type check?

Comment: `And if value is empty it will be automatically convert to array` ?

Comment: Why do you want to convert the value to an array if it's empty?

Comment: Your edit **And if value is empty it will be automatically convert to array** makes this question useless it seems.

Comment: Well it could make sense to replace an “empty” value with an empty array, so that you can have a foreach after it without having to wrap _that_ in an `if(is_array)` check again.

Comment: If what @CBroe said is what you are trying to achieve then simply type casting a `NULL` value would result in an empty array.

Comment: Do one thing , check for array or typecast from where you are calling the function . If check result is true then call the function otherwise not . This will speed up the process and will decrease the execution time .

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of PHP's [type hinting](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

```
public function(array $arg){
 ....
}
```

But this will not convert the `$arg` to an array, you can allow `NULL` values like this:

```
// PHP 7.1 and above
public function(?array $arg){
 ....
}

// Or set the default value to NULL
public function(array $arg = NULL){
 ....
}
```

Or simply use [`is_array($arg)`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) that will return `TRUE` if `$arg` is an array.

In order to convert a value to an array you can [type cast](https://secure.php.net/language.types.type-juggling#language.types.typecasting) it:

```
(array) '';   // Gives an array with one element equal to ''
(array) NULL; // Gives an empty array
(array) 0;    // Gives an array with one element equal to 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Type hinting would work, however [under version restrictions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).

A primitive approach.

```
if(gettype($dataid) === 'array'){
    // Do the needful here
}
```

Would be very reliable still...

Answer (score 0):

Thats what you want:

```
if (is_array($array) or ($array instanceof Traversable)) {
    ...
}
```